# Nginx Redirect using /etc/hosts for Upstream Resolution

Tags: file, redirect, nginx, dynamic, hosts

This is probably going to be a stretch, but it seems worth asking. Let's say I have a static Angular web app on `nginx-host` (linux) along with the following /etc/hosts file, automatically generated for the host by some stringy configuration management tool:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.1  internalhost
```

Next, I have a stock Nginx configuration for `nginx-host`, nothing fancy is happening with the server blocks - with this problematic location block:

```
location ^~ /app {
    return 301 http://internalhost/end/point
}
```

The problem is that this block returns **precisely** the url listed in the location block without any sort of translation from `internalhost` to the appropriate IP, resulting in client-side errors - and I need it to resolve that IP before handing it back.

Please note, we can't use maps or upstreams here. The Immovable Wall here is that our configuration system handles all service discovery and host-dependency resolution by doing lookups and generating hostfiles, and it's entirely separated from our internal nginx configuration, so we can't connect the lookups to the nginx setup to allow for dynamic maps or upstreams. This is also happening across several isolated segments of network for varied testing environments, so it's a hard requirement that we reference the nginx host's `/etc/hosts` file to resolve the host name *before* passing back the redirect path, as `internalhost` can be anything from `dev-internalhost` to `production-backup-internalhost`, all of which have distinct IPs.

Note: `proxy_pass` is not a solution here, we need the redirect for SSO purposes, and when the request is made to the `internalhost` location, the request params need to carry on through to the `internalhost` machine from the `nginx-host`, and the client needs to see the redirect to know that it's now on speaking terms with the `internalhost` server.

Edit for clarity: the client has no way to resolve `internalapp` on its own: `nginx-host` has a static UI, a link on that UI hits the `/app` endpoint, and nginx needs to pass back an IP-based link derived from the generated local hosts file. `internalapp` has no DNS records at all aside from the local hosts file - but the IP address in the hosts file would resolve to something like `dev-internalapp.example.com` that could actually be reached

Answer (score 0):

The hostname in the 301 redirect is just text that's sent to the webbrowser.

The vast majority of clients out there will use DNS to find the IP address from the hostname in the URL.

If you have browsers "out there" on the Internet, they will have to have a fully qualified domainname (e.g. www.example.com) as internal or something similar will never point back to you. In this case you will have to change the message sent back by nginx. It's trivial if you have control over the configuration to do that...

If you only have internal hosts, your internal DNS should be more than able to allow internal hosts to properly resolve "internalhost" to its internal IP address. In essence, make sure they send a searchdomain record along with the DHCP responses.

How to setup the DHCP and DNS inside a company is relatively easy if they have an internal network/IT team that knows what they are doing.
If they have a mess -that happens every so often- nothing will work properly, no matter what you do.

A lot depends on how they set things up, but in general to make names like "internalhost" resolv internally to an IP address, I'd use:

1. pick an internal domainname (if they have not already). e.g. `.local` is an option, or historically `in.example.com` (where `example.com` is their external name). It does not have to be known externally, it just must not be used externally. Having it known externally makes it slightly harder, so avoid that.
2. DHCP: I'd set DHCP to emit the optional "search domain". How to do that depends on what DHCP server they use, but e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/481453/set-search-domain-on-dhcp-server-without-changing-domain-name shows an example. I typically make sure it emits `in.example.com, example.com` as that makes it easier on typing domain names.
3. Internal DNS: now just add on the internal DNS server(s) an A record for `internalhost.in.example.com.` and point that to your RFC1918 address.
4. Optional: I'd make sure the firewalls disallow internal clients from using external DNS servers - or (better?) redirect them transparently to the internal DNS server(s). that way you avoid users setting e.g. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as DNS servers, overruling what they get from the DHCP server, and hence not seeing your internal names.

That's it. http://internalhost/whatever will now go to the machine with the IP address given in step 3 above and browsers will send a Host: header (if you have virtual hosts!) of `internalhost`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Everything is internal, so internal DNS is probably the only choice given everything I've seen over 2 days of googling and perusing docs - but I haven't seen any means of making nginx use internal dns to resolve `internalhost` before sending that URL back, could you elaborate on that a bit? 

In case it clarifies something, the client has no way to resolve that part on its own: the nginx has a static UI, a link on the UI hits the `/app` endpoint, and nginx needs to pass back an IP-based link from the local hosts file, `internalapp` has no DNS record aside from that

Comment: added to the answer

Comment: Thanks again - unfortunately, we fall under the 'mess' category. `internalhost` is a stand-in for an application name that might look like `foo_ws` in practice. We have those apps assigned to boxes using a custom in-house service discovery mechanism that doesn't use DNS - and as we currently only have one DNS instance, we can't register `foo_ws` to anything as there are generally upwards of 10 different environments with `foo_ws`, so an A record would either thrash or be useless. DNS is very sadly out on this one, we have to make it work with Nginx if at all

Comment: Also, the client is just a browser, and we can't affect any client computers, so I think we'll just have to figure something else out or change how the application expects that to work. Thanks again for all the info though